# check if a character is carriage return

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i would like to remove the last line from my string.. the nsstring object here is _text. My thoughts are to scan characters from the end and if i found a carriage return symbol i substring to that index, and finnish. But i don't want to remove every carriage return, just the last one.

So i would like to do something like this:

```
for (int i = [_text length] ; i>0; i--) {
    char character = [_text characterAtIndex:i];
    if (character == @"\n") {
       _text = [_text substringToIndex:i];
     return;
    }
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle the last char being whitespace or CR.
You also had a bug where you needed length - 1 in the for loop.

Here's some working code:

```
    NSString *_text = [NSString stringWithString:@"line number 1\nline number 2\nlinenumber 3\n  "];

    // make sure you handle ending whitespace and ending carriage return
    _text = [_text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    NSUInteger i;
    unichar cr = '\n';
    for (i = [_text length] - 1; i>0; i--) 
    {
        if ([_text characterAtIndex:i] == cr) 
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (index > 0)
    {
        _text = [_text substringToIndex:i];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", _text);
```

This outputs:
2011-09-22 08:00:10.473 Craplet[667:707] line number 1
line number 2

Comment: Thanks! Your solution was perfect to me! Thank you very very much!

Comment: Yeah, but that is a newline character, not a carriage return.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is correct, but you're checking if a char is equal to a literal string pointer! Try this instead:

```
 if (character == '\n')
       ...
```

By the way, this is a newline. A carriage return is represented by `'\r'`. Also, as a word of caution, review your memory management. If `_text` is an ivar, you may want to use a setter instead. Otherwise, you're assigning an autoreleased object to it that probably won't exist anymore in a latter path, causing other problems.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now i see that it's going to take to long to do this what i want. Maybe there is another way to remove the last line in a string?

Comment: I think this is a nice way to do it. Maybe others can suggest different things, which doesn't happen to come to my mind at this moment. To speed it up, I'd use a C string. Then you can use an array subscript in its pointer to iterate without having to call an external library just to find a character in a certain index. (I could write this code for you, but I have no time! I'm leaving the computer now for an appointment, but once I come back in 1.3 hours or so, unless you figured it out or someone else wrote it, I'll update the answer.)

Comment: If you want to trim off the last line of a multi-line string, there are several NSString methods that can help.  `rangeOfString:@"\n" options:NSBackwardsSearch` will return the position of the newline char, and `substringToIndex` will then return the "head" of the string to that point.

Answer (score 2):

You might try:

```
NSString *newString = [originalString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

It will remove all leading and trailing carriage returns '\r' and new lines '\n'.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but i only need to find the last \r symbol and then substring to that symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
if([_text characterAtIndex:[albumName length]-1] == '\n') //compare last char
```